# Kivy Popup confirmation to delete listview item

Tags: python, popup, kivy

I would like to delete an item from the listview if the user click on the delete meeting button.

In that case, a popup will appear and ask for confirmation of the deletion of the meeting.

Everything is working fine expect when the user click on the Yes button (to confirm the deletion of the meeting), I didn't manage to remove the meeting from the listview.

I would like to write for the Yes button:

```
on_press : self.meeting_list.adapter.data.remove(selection) and self.meeting_list._trigger_reset_populate()
```

---

```
class MeetingDB(BoxLayout):
    meeting_list = ObjectProperty()
    attendance_list = ObjectProperty()

    def delete_meeting(self):
        if self.meeting_list.adapter.selection:
            selection = self.meeting_list.adapter.selection[0].text

            self.box_popup = BoxLayout(orientation = 'horizontal')
            self.box_popup.add_widget(Label(text = "Confirm the deletion of the meeting ?"))

            self.box_popup.add_widget(Button(
                text = "Yes",
                on_press = App.get_running_app().root.ids.meeting_list.adapter.data.remove(selection),
                size_hint = (0.215, 0.075)))

            self.box_popup.add_widget(Button(
                text = "No",
                on_press = lambda *args: self.popup_exit.dismiss(),
                size_hint=(0.215, 0.075)))

            self.popup_exit = Popup(title = "Delete Meeting Confirmation",
                content = self.box_popup,
                size_hint = (0.4, 0.4),
                auto_dismiss = True)

            self.popup_exit.open()

            #self.meeting_list.adapter.data.remove(selection)
            #self.meeting_list._trigger_reset_populate()
```

Kv file:

```
<MeetingDB>:
    orientation:'vertical'
    meeting_list: meeting_view
    attendance_list: attendance_view

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "40dp"

        Button:
            text: 'Add meeting'
            size_hint_x: 20
            on_press: root.add_meeting()
        Button:
            text: 'Delete Meeting'
            size_hint_x: 20
            on_press: root.delete_meeting()

    ListView:
        id: meeting_view
        adapter:
            ListAdapter(data = app.r, cls = main.MeetingListButton)

    ListView:
        id: attendance_view
        adapter:
            ListAdapter(data = [], cls = main.AttendanceListButton, selection_mode = 'multiple')
```

Comment: Create a function for your `on_press` instead, and do the work in there. Because this doesn't work as JavaScript where you bind the function call to a event. You've actively executed `remove()` already when you try to bind it to the button. Instead, do `on_press=self.remove_thing` and define a function called `def remove_thing(self)` where you do the actual work. (Notice how I did not do `on_press=self.remove_thing()` but instead just `self.remove_thing`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact without the parenthesis, I can call the remove_thing function. But I got the error remove_thing() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.

Comment: `def remove_thing(self, object_pressed)` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is that you're storing the execution of `remove()` as the bound function for `on_press` and not the function `remove`.

So doing the following would make more sense:

```
on_press = App.get_running_app().root.ids.meeting_list.adapter.data.remove
```

But I would convert the call to a user-made function instead so that you can get better control of what happens, by doing something like:

```
class MeetingDB(BoxLayout):
    meeting_list = ObjectProperty()

    def remove_thing(self, event):
        selection = self.meeting_list.adapter.selection[0].text
        App.get_running_app().root.ids.meeting_list.adapter.data.remove(selection),

    def delete_meeting(self):
        if self.meeting_list.adapter.selection:
            self.box_popup = BoxLayout(orientation = 'horizontal')
            self.box_popup.add_widget(Label(text = "Confirm the deletion of the meeting ?"))

            self.box_popup.add_widget(Button(
                text = "Yes",
                on_press = self.remove_thing
                size_hint = (0.215, 0.075))
            )

            self.popup_exit.open()
```

Now, I don't have Kivy installed and I can't test this code.
So apologies if it's not perfect, but you should get the idea.